# Populating table for more than 20k rows it takes lot of time and page becomes unresponsive when it done

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My table format is as follows   :

```
 <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
              <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
              <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
              <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
            </tr>
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Fix it by not loading 20K rows into a browser's memory.

Comment: Not really clear what's being asked? Are you wondering how to improve browser performance or break apart the problem into smaller chunks? What have you tried?

Comment: Do you really need 20k rows on one page ? Paging your results seems like a good idea for so many results.

Comment: Hi all , My use case is with more than ~20 k . Is this not possible with angular js ?  Secondly for How insensitive means its a big lag between i type and it displays on text field in browser.

Comment: i am displaying packet capture in the browser and i required all of them to be on page at all time . Is any angularjs expert out there ?

Comment: @nishantpathak I understood, I was just kidding. The problem is not with angular, it's the browser that can't handle such a big table. You'll probably have to load just a part of the table at a time, and replace it with another chunk when needed (basically, implement pagination).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, you do not want to display 20k rows at the same time.  Even if Angular weren't part of the story, 20k rows is too many for the browser to handle well.

> i am displaying packet capture in the browser and i required all of
>   them to be on page at all time

This statement does not justify putting all of the rows on the page at the same time.  The reason is that you can never see 20k rows at the same time.  I mean, my display right now only has about 1k pixels.  Unless you created a visualization using the data (and that would still be slow with 20k points), you will never see them all at the same time.

What you want to do is come up with a user experience that allows the viewing of all the data without having all of the rows in the DOM.  Out of sight, out of mind (from the DOM's perspective).  There are several ways to do this.  Some common ways to do this are paging and "virtual scrolling".  These solutions usually assume that your server is paging the data for you, but there is nothing stopping you from adapting it to use client-side data, assuming you have it all in memory already.

If you are looking for a way to do it without paging or virtual scrolling, you will be waiting a long time.  The DOM isn't capable enough to help you out here.

However, some people have come up with solutions in Angular for virtual scrolling:

- [angular-virtual-scroll](https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll)
- [How to do it](http://blog.stackfull.com/2013/02/angularjs-virtual-scrolling-part-1/)

Comment: virtual scroll will be a good option . But as you suggested user will not be able to visualize it adding filters and pagination will be more useful. Thanks for sharing thoughts .